# Forcing bluetooth for iPhone incoming calls

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, headphones

Is there anyway to force the iPhone to always use Bluetooth for incoming calls? - I'm on a motorcycle and have my iPhone set to auto answer calls, problem is it answers with the built in iPhone headphone/microphone instead of the paired and connected bluetooth headset.

I also cannot answer with the button on the bluetooth headset as it is inside my helmet.

Any ideas? - My iPhone is jailbroken if that helps.

Comment: how do you set to auto answer on the iPhone ?

Comment: Using CallController - an app you have in Cydia after jailbreaking your iPhone. I also spoke to it's developer and he says he cannot find a way to switch to bluetooth on call answer either :/

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this via the iPhone itself, but there are voice-controlled Bluetooth headsets (such as the [BlueAnt Q2](http://www.blueant.com.au/q2/features.php)) that would allow you to take the call on the headset without pushing a button.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you still want a solution for this, but Cardo makes in-helmet bluetooth receivers that are awesome. The send/receive button is on the outside of the helmet then you install the mic/speaker inside (simple process).

Answer (score 2):

You can set the phone to use the headset or speaker by default under the accessibility options.

- Settings
- General
- Accessibility
- Scroll down to interaction section
- Call Audio Routing
- Choose headset

Answer (score 0):

1. Bring "Bluetooth headset with multiple pairing version",
2. Iphone's sim insert in to other mobile like "Nokia" etc.,
3. Now set call divert "if not answered" with 20 to 30 seconds mode,
4. Then replace your sim in to iphone.
5. Now Pair Bluetooth with Nokia & Iphone also,
6. While riding bike if you get any call on Iphone, call will be ringing for your particular time & then divert to Nokia which have already auto call answer mode is enable, that's it !